# Query with reserve word column used to work in SQL Server 2008 no longer works with SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I'm assisting one of my co-worker who couldn't get our application to work. I found out that he was using SQL Server 2012 and the error comes down to the application runs the following SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    SMS_INSTITUTIONS.SMS_INSTITUTION_NR, 
    SMS_INSTITUTIONS.ID, 
    SMS_INSTITUTIONS.NAME, 
    SMS_INSTITUTIONS.EXTERNAL 
FROM 
    SMS_INSTITUTIONS
```

So I tested this by running this query in SQL Server 2008 using Management Studio and it runs fine. However upon testing this exact same query running the same database in SQL Server 2012 with Management Studio 2012 I get

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'EXTERNAL'.

We found out it works when we put [] around the `EXTERNAL` reserved word then the query works with the SQL Server 2012 database.

```
SELECT 
    SMS_INSTITUTIONS.SMS_INSTITUTION_NR, 
    SMS_INSTITUTIONS.ID, 
    SMS_INSTITUTIONS.NAME, 
    SMS_INSTITUTIONS.[EXTERNAL] 
FROM 
    SMS_INSTITUTIONS
```

Do you know if this is a new restriction on SQL Server 2012 or is there setting I need to enable? I Googled around but come up short with any direct explanation on this so far.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`EXTERNAL` has been a reserved keyword since SQL Server **2005**.

My only thought is that you would have been running your 2008 database in the `80` (SQL Server 2000) compatibility mode. That mode is **no longer supported** in SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Thank you marc_s, that is exactly what it is.  I double check my SQL server 2008 and it looks to be default to SQL Server 2000 (80), i never new about this setting before.  Upon changing it to 90 or 100 then I get the same error.